# @Secured checking role from constants string in java class

Tags: java, spring

Can Spring's @Secured annotation check the role from constants string I've populated into a java class? Currently, it's checking the role from database.

For example:
Constants.java

```
public class Constants {
    public static final String CASH_TRANSFER = "ROLE_CASHTRANSFER";
}
```

MainPage.java

```
@Secured(Constants.CASH_TRANSFER)
public class MainPage {
    // will be authorized
}

@Secured(Constants.COLLATERAL)
public class MainPage {
    // will not authorized
}
```

Comment: use in this pattern - @Secured("ADMIN") to @Secured("ROLE_ADMIN"). First you have to get the role from the DB and Apply in the Annotation

Comment: @LovaChittumuri Well, my intention is to ignore DB, and just checking from constants class.

Comment: Then use the Constant in the @Secured(ProvideConstant)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've found that `@Secured` annotation matches the given role to a "pool"
This pool is `Collection<GrantedAuthority>`. And in my case, this pool is constructed right after a user logged in. Previously, it collects roles from my database, but I changed that, so now it collects from my `Constants` class, populates all `static final String` to an `ArrayList` using `Reflection`